# Force feed readers to display the body of a post in an RSS 2.0 feed

Tags: rss

I have a feed which I'd like to be able to read in a feed reader.  It will only display the title and description.  Can I change something in the feed or my reader that will allow me to view the body of the posts?

Here's a sample of the feed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
  <title>NarrativeScience</title>
  <link>http://www.narrativescience.com</link>
  <description>Narrative Science</description>
  <language>en</language>

  <item>
    <title>Kelly Services Earnings Preview</title>
    <link>http://www.narrativescience.com </link>
    <description>Kelly Services will unveil its latest earnings on Wednesday, August 10.</description>
    <category domain="ticker-symbol"> KELYA </category>
    <body> <![CDATA[ <p>
     Investors are on the edge of their collective seats, hoping that <b>Kelly Services</b> (Nasdaq: KELYA) will top analyst expectations for the fifth consecutive quarter. The company will unveil its latest earnings on Wednesday, August 10. Kelly Services is a global workforce solutions provider operating in all major markets throughout the world. It assigns professional and technical employees in the fields of creative services, education, legal, and health care. 
     </p><p>
     <strong>What analysts say: <br /></strong>
     </p><ul><li><b>Buy, sell, or hold?:</b> The majority of analysts back Kelly Services as a buy. But with 60% of analysts rating it a buy, Kelly Services is still below the mean analyst rating of its nearest 10 competitors, which average 76.4% buys. Analysts don't like Kelly Services as much as competitor <b>TrueBlue</b> overall. Eight out of nine analysts rate TrueBlue a buy compared to three of five for Kelly Services. Analysts haven't adjusted their rating of Kelly Services for the past three months. </li><li><b>Revenue Forecasts:</b> On average, analysts predict $1.37 billion in revenue this quarter. That would represent a rise of 13.2% from the year-ago quarter. </li><li><b>Wall Street Earnings Expectations:</b> The average analyst estimate is earnings of 25 cents per share. Estimates range from 20 cents to 29 cents. </li></ul><p>
     <strong>What our community says: <br /></strong>The majority of CAPS All Stars see KELYA as a good bet, with 66.7% giving it an "outperform" rating. The majority of the Fools are in agreement with the All Stars as 77.1% give it an "outperform" rating. Fools are bullish on Kelly Services, though the message boards have been quiet lately with only 41 <a href='http://caps.fool.com/Ticker/KELYA.aspx'>posts</a>   in the past 30 days. Kelly Services' bearish CAPS rating of one out of five stars falls short of the Fool community sentiment. 
     </p><p>
     <strong>Management: <br /></strong>
     </p>Now let's look at how efficient management is at running the business. Traditionally, margins represent the efficiency with which companies capture portions of sales dollars. The following table shows gross, operating, and net margins over the past four quarters. 
     <table><tr><td><p><b>Quarter</b></p></td><td><p><b>Q1</b></p></td><td><p><b>Q4</b></p></td><td><p><b>Q3</b></p></td><td><p><b>Q2</b></p></td></tr><tr><td><p><b>Gross Margin</b></p></td><td><p>16%</p></td><td><p>16.3%</p></td><td><p>16.1%</p></td><td><p>15.8%</p></td></tr><tr><td><p><b>Operating Margin</b></p></td><td><p>0.1%</p></td><td><p>1.3%</p></td><td><p>1.1%</p></td><td><p>0.7%</p></td></tr><tr><td><p><b>Net Margin</b></p></td><td><p>0.1%</p></td><td><p>1.1%</p></td><td><p>0.7%</p></td><td><p>0.3%</p></td></tr></table>
     <p>
     One final thing: If you want to keep tabs on Kelly Services movements, and for more analysis on the company, make sure you add it to your <a href="http://my.fool.com/watchlist.add?ticker=KELYA">Watchlist</a>. 
     </p><p>
     <i>Try any of our Foolish newsletter services <a href='http://www.fool.com/shop/newsletters/index.aspx'>free for 30 days</a>. We Fools may not all hold the same opinions, but we all believe that <a href='http://www.fool.com/shop/newsletters/index.aspx'>considering a diverse range of insights</a> makes us better investors. The Motley Fool has a <a href='http://www.fool.com/Legal/fool-disclosure-policy.aspx'>disclosure policy</a>.</i> 
     </p> ]]> </body>
    <pubDate>2011-08-05 08:09:14.408000</pubDate>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">4e3ba52a18567f40380003a2</guid>
  </item>

  <!-- other items -->

</channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`You have a <body> tag instead of a <description> tag in the item element.  There is no <body> tag in RSS 2.0.  Both the channel and item elements have description sub-elements.  Try changing your <body> tags to <description> tags.`

[See this](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html) for the RSS 2.0 specification.